# Unable to add Google App platform in Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook, google-play-console

Hi I am trying to add Android app platform in my Facebook app in developers.facebook.com but when i add package id in Package Names field then it given an error

**There was a problem verifying this package name. Please check and try again.**

and

**Error found while validating app-ads.txt. PACKAGE NAME: We couldn't find your developer website URL in your app's store listing**

I have created app in my Google Play Console with all required details but still there's problem verifying this package name.

Below are the reference screenshots of Google Play Console and Facebook App Platform.

[image: Google Play App]

[image: Contact Details]

[image: Facebook Android App Platform]

**NOTE:** I have already uploaded  **app-ads.txt**

**EDIT**
Reference link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/optimization/best-practices/troubleshoot-app-ads/

[image]

As per above screenshots i have put all the details in my google play console app but still i am getting this error.Please let me know what am i missing or share the steps to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i believe I have found the answer. In order for your Developer URL to show on your store listing you have to add the app-ad.txt under the Developer Page section in Google play. Ive added images (they wont let me show them), but also here is the documentation I found, which also mentions where to put the URL, and that it does require 24 hours to show. Shame that the updated url takes so long to show that its challenging to confirm if it worked. Hope this helps

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9873827?hl=en

edit: their facebook documentation does say to put it in contact details, but also notes it could take 7 days to show. so if thats the case the above would just be a safeguard and we just have to wait 7 days for our contact details url to update on the google play store.
"Note: There can be a delay of up to 7 days when updating your app store listing."

Comment: I have already uploaded app-ads.txt file content

Comment: and waited 7 days?

Comment: I've successfully added the Package Names for 2 of my games so far(the appads is in the website on my console's app's Store Settings), and I want to do it for the third but kept receiving this error. But when I put in the same package name for the game on another app on facebook's developers page, I won't see the error. All these while the developer website on the console's developer's page is empty.

Comment: There is nowhere on "Developer Page" in the Play Store developer portal to add app-ads.txt. The only URL field is "Website address", but that's for the main homepage address.

Answer (score 0):

in app.ads.txt, update two lines in which one line should be with business id and another with app id.
it worked for us. i hope the same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your `app-ads.txt` file to UTF-8 and re-upload. I was stuck for hours until I tried this and it worked.